# C program: when I use malloc function, I find that there are always more bytes than size of the array

Tags: c

Maybe the new code can explain what I mean.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    int i_size = 2, j_size = 5, k_size = 5, l_size = 6, m_size = 6;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0; 
    printf("ptr1\n");
    int** ptr1 = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * i_size);
    for(i = 0; i < i_size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", ptr1 + i);
    }
    printf("ptr2\n");
    int** ptr2 =  (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * j_size);
    for(j = 0; j < j_size; j++){
        printf("%d\n", ptr2 + j);
    }
    printf("ptr3\n");
    int** ptr3 =  (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * k_size);
    for(k = 0; k < k_size; k++){
        printf("%d\n", ptr3 + k);
    }
    printf("ptr4\n");
    int** ptr4 =  (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * l_size);
    for(l = 0; l < l_size; l++){
        printf("%d\n", ptr4 + l);
    }
    printf("ptr5\n");
    int** ptr5 =  (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * m_size);
    for(m = 0; m < m_size; m++){
         printf("%d\n", ptr5 + m);
    }
    free(ptr1);
    free(ptr2);
    free(ptr3);
    free(ptr4);
    free(ptr5); 
    return 0;
}
```

The result is as below:

[image: Result]

It is funny that it seems for `malloc` function, the minimun size of array is 32 bytes. And the OS seems to preserve 8 bytes space because when I found that for `l_size`, it has 64 bytes. It means that if you want to malloc a 48-byte array, the OS will allocate more than 48-byte space.

update above

=====

My code is shown as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    int i_size = 5, j_size = 6, i = 0, j = 0; 
    printf("Addresses of two dimensional pointer\n");
    int** ptr = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * i_size);
    printf("%d:\t%d\n", &ptr, ptr);
    for(i = 0; i < i_size; i++){
        *(ptr + i) = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * j_size);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < i_size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < j_size; j++){
            *(*(ptr+i) + j) = i * 2 + j;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < i_size; i++){
        printf("%d:\t%d\n", ptr + i, *(ptr + i));
    }
    printf("==\n");
    for(i = 0; i < i_size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < j_size; j++){
            printf("%d:\t%d\t%d\n",*(ptr + i) + j, *(*(ptr + i) + j), ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("==\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < i_size; i++){
        free(*(ptr + i));
    } 
    free(ptr);

    return 0; 
}
```

And the result as the folloing picture shows:

[image]

The code is running on the windows 10, 64-bit and compiled with TDM-GCC4.9.2 of Dev C++.

I am confused by the red block. Why is always 8 more bytes than the size of array. If I change the value of `i_size` to 6, it seems that the OS will give 64 bytes to `ptr` but not 48.

[image: The result of changing the value of i_size to 6]

I expect that the value `12021664` should be `12021648`. If I change the value of `i_size` to 7, it is ok:
[image: the result of changing the value of i_size to 7]

But when the value of `i_size` is 8, I expect the value `10710960` should be `10710944`. But it doesn't work.

[image: the result of changing the value of i_size to 8]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Don't use `%d` for pointer values. Use `%p` instead.

Comment: Please cut and paste output text rather than posting links to images. Those can't be searched and can't be read by everyone

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Please explain what you think is strange about the output you get?

Comment: You have no array in your code so the question makes no sense.

Comment: @Fredrik well he allocates memory dynamically, so it _is_ a kind of array here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just want to calculate the offset directly without converting hex number to decimal number.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I update my question.

Comment: @smielqf the answer below as well as its comments are still correct.

Comment: @Jabberwocky OK, I just can not figure it out. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: On any platform : if `p` is a pointer, the value  of `p + n` is exacly the value of `p` plus `n` times the size of a pointer in bytes. On a 32 bit platform the size of a pointer is usually 32 bits (4 bytes), on a 64 bit platform the size of a pointe is usually 64 bits (8 bytes). You are obviously on a 64 bit platform. Make a simpler sample with just one array of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

`ptr` points to an array of `int *`.  On your system, it appears that pointers are 8 bytes in size, so each member of the array is 8 bytes.

When you then print the address of each member as `ptr + i`, you see that they each differ by 8.

Also, you should be using `%p` to print pointers instead of `%d`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Regarding the specific memory addresses returned by `malloc`, those are an implementation detail of the library.  There is no requirement that successive allocations should be adjacent in memory.  In fact, it makes sense that they are not adjacent because there is likely some metadata being stored in those in-between addresses which is being used internally by `malloc`.

Comment: Well, I think `%d` is not the key to the problem. I jus want to calculate the offset directly without converting hex number to decimal number, since the value of address is an integer. And I know the address is 8-byte long. But when I change the value of `i_size` to 6, why does the OS give 64 bytes to `ptr` but not 48.

Comment: @smielqf no, the `%d` is not the actual problem, but using `%d` instead of `%p` is still wrong. You are just lucky that you get something more or less usefull with`%d`. Addresses on your platform are 64 bits and `int`s may be 32 bit values on your platform. But the answer _is_  correct. Just take a piece of paper and a pencil and draw the memory layout and you'll understand. BTW also try to change the values of `i_size` and `j_size`, the difference will still be 8.

Comment: @smielqf See my edit.  There's no requirement that those address are adjacent.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I got the point of 8 bytes for a pointer in 64-bits OS, but I do not think that is what I want. And I update my question. Thanks.

Comment: @smielqf I think the last paragraph of this answer applies.